# Adding multiple key/values

Tags: mongodb

In my database.collection i.e. db.blog.posts I am trying to add a key and value that itself has multiple keys and values.

Current collection:

```
db.blog.posts.findOne()
"title":"blog posts"
```

I tried using $set, $push but nothing seems to work.

This also didn't work when I tried adding single collection:

```
db.blog.posts.updateOne({"title":"blog posts"}, {"$set":{"comments":[{"comment":"good post", "author":"john","votes":0}]}})
```

Nor insertOne instead of updateOne and I even tried with:

```
var myEmployee=[
{"comment":"good post", "author":"john", "votes":0},
{"comment":"i thought it was too short", "author":"claire","votes":3},
{"comment":"free watches", "author":"claire","votes":-1},
];
db.blog.posts.insert(myEmployee)
```

This is what I want:

```
"title" : "A blog post",
"comments" : [
    {
        "name" : "joe",
        "email" : "joe@example.com",
        "content" : "nice post."
    },
    {
        "name" : "bob",
        "email" : "bob@example.com",
        "content" : "good post."
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updateOne` command you have should have created an array for comments with a single entry. If you wanted multiple entries, you can just add multiple objects to the array in the update. The `$set` operator will change the value of the key to what you set as the second parameter.

```
db['blog.posts'].updateOne({"title":"blog posts"}, {
  "$set": {
    "comments":[
      {
        "name" : "joe",
        "email" : "joe@example.com",
        "content" : "nice post."
      },
      {
        "name" : "bob",
        "email" : "bob@example.com",
        "content" : "good post."
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

If you want to add additional items to the comments, this can be done with `$push`. The `$push` operator adds to the array.

```
db['blog.posts'].updateOne({"title":"blog posts"}, {
  "$push": {
    "comments": {
      "comment": "good post",
      "author": "john",
      "votes": 0
    }
  }
})
```

[Docs for $set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html)
[Docs for $push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html)

NB the examples above are for a collection named 'blog.posts' rather than a database named 'blog' and a collection names 'posts'. Ideally, brackets should be used for the property accessor where the collection name is not a [valid JavaScript identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/identifier) although the dot notation in the question still works.

Comment: ahhhhh...my mistake was i was adding square brackets after each sub key-value pairs and thanks for correcting that. Second problem was, i was not using the right code to display. To display multiple lines i was using db.blog.posts.findOne() instead of posts.find()